# PHP - send value to external aspx form and get value

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I want to get value from the ASP form, but all my attempts fail.
It is a form on the website here: https://www.dovera.sk/overenia/dlznici/zoznam-dlznikov

For example I try this value 36471224 and form (on this site) return values. I am trying to get the CURL request, but I have not succeeded yet. Is it at all possible (I'm desperate)? I will be very glad if at least somebody is navigating me in the right way. Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google developer tool to get the curl request

[image: cURL request google developer]

Assuming that the variables doesn't change and effect , you can come to the above solution

**Solution:**

```
<?php
function fetch_value($str, $find_start = '', $find_end = '')
{
    if ($find_start == '')
    {
        return '';
    }
    $start = strpos($str, $find_start);
    if ($start === false)
    {
        return '';
    }
    $length = strlen($find_start);
    $substr = substr($str, $start + $length);
    if ($find_end == '')
    {
        return $substr;
    }
    $end = strpos($substr, $find_end);
    if ($end === false)
    {
        return $substr;
    }
    return substr($substr, 0, $end);
}

$post_page = "https://ep.dovera.sk/PublicZone/Neplatici/NeplaticiWeb.aspx";
$search_term = "36471224";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $post_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');



$post_string = 'ctl00%24Main%24GlobalScriptManager=ctl00%24Main%24PageUpdatePanel%7Cctl00%24Main%24btnSearch&__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24Main%24btnSearch&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=DNsB8hM9wz%2FW6xBtn%2FZkhbF6O476J2gngpFKhZ69zbFcSWgUS1mBE0yhm%2BN2G2rYrkyri%2FJdB5zLpoULSuhZCa7%2FJLp6gFVRLeIddMXOUbjS5vvl8sLtVZLZRWA4f8xPTP%2BvklzJvMk1AHGEPuWTL5CkWIzK4j4iNMEWiAw36Dikxs9fW7U7tkbrAwKLwnd%2BRNbaYUV%2FXG74uKswnRCcp6UChwpQb%2FruBXB4F3O1i04y3wLn1je0SS%2BW6NqRtuPUog3eHChPM%2FzrRW9Uap8qHIBKbKWvUZZalTYQBImPMLo7MMn2e5MyeJlBHBvs27mgM3l0%2F9upFZXTYz0Qf6P0WwDsn8zGQgvUgsyU82%2BxOO4o9KPx0CoDj4970zOBTnTY%2B4M8LrYhkaRSAPe0iUFbVbN8YaaIaL55XDgSvC%2FCI22Jqu%2FmGWGi9JVDV11nKJavwGmZDqEk2npf2cuu99sjex0%2B8hXeUSzPNKhpyVgJcNs6dGM%2Bas0ezeVcc8fmue1jiwhVBM6mKaapdOBSI%2FXOjIj%2FCvP3cC9%2FR4J%2FBpqxwPk%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=BD62B0C4&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=&__EVENTVALIDATION=cJqi2bjVZY21%2FUyBXt2IDjfqX7O%2B7rlSpeoBTVDLlEo2NS0H7I6q55OoYLV0mgze9JUnEv4x9YlnWxxe5F%2BmR4NAd%2FrohDoYiaOFlVboUhIeJhFIACbORPQRemXeo9CwTQRCEPZ5ZKcixnFvdfFORoNB744G5BEsHON1MyGvF1sic5O2W6RYSxRfM2yslzXrwcBUPsT2mryIEHinE7awsBjCnFJIV%2BfknQq0zVjeHS0BobfJolodHqPkcXDVgurT&ctl00%24Main%24hdLinkNewWindow=&ctl00%24Main%24hdLinkTarget=&ctl00%24Main%24hdXVal=0&ctl00%24Main%24txtSearch='.$search_term.'&ctl00%24Main%24hdwatermark=Zadajte%20meno%20a%20priezvisko%2C%20rodn%C3%A9%20%C4%8D%C3%ADslo%2C%20obchodn%C3%BD%20n%C3%A1zov%20alebo%20I%C4%8CO&recaptcha_challenge_field=03AJIzXZ6kCvOklH6XGTrILEvfL1K6CWph19yWrUyh2B9QdBxFh9LJJ-mN4K2KwUGpDBKN6UCBJ9VuFguJEtMYoB8_2ZjQWnunD3wH_LLuojbCzbzJ1RRyJiq58zbfynXLaKJbAlUcoarElCRfN7VC9xv1V8rfWZCPoiCa2YVDi6ZPqJ2KCDFp6PHXQO96nR-0-7XSS5Y329sX&recaptcha_response_field=&__ASYNCPOST=true&';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$name = fetch_value($content, '<span id="Main_gwNeplatici_lblNazov_0">', '</span>');
$address = fetch_value($content, '<span id="Main_gwNeplatici_lblAdresa_0">', '</span>');
$ico  = fetch_value($content, '<span id="Main_gwNeplatici_lblICO_0">', '</span>');
$amount  = fetch_value($content, '<span id="Main_gwNeplatici_lblSuma_0" style="font-weight:bold;">', '</span>');
echo 'Name : '.$name.'<br>Address :'.$address.'<br> Ico : '.$ico.'<br>Amount : '.$amount ;



?>
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: uff, this is not the answer. this is the solution! thank you very much for your help. I owe you a beer :)

Comment: Mark it as a solution ;) and let's take this beer :D